# Authenticating Facebook with PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I am having a little trouble authenticating with the below code.

I have a page that produces a loginUrl for the user to login/authenticate my app on Facebook:

```
<?php
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream, read_friendlists, user_birthday', 'redirect_uri' => 'complete.php'));
?>
<div id="connect_facebook">
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Connect to Facebook</a>
</div>
```

And my complete.php has a script that does the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    pop_db();
});

function pop_db() {
    $.post(
        "pop_db.php",
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

And my pop_db.php file looks like:

```
<?php
require_once('constants.php');

$response = array();

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) {
    try {
        // make API calls
        $response['code'] = "success";
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    $response['code'] = "failure";
    $response['userID'] = $facebook->getUser();
    $response['access_token'] = $facebook->getAccessToken();
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

And constants.php has my secret info for the Facebook object (and it also creates the $facebook object).

My issue is that when I do this using "complete.php" as the redirect and try to do the API calls async using this jQuery, I get back a response that userID = 0 (meaning the user isn't logged in) but it seems like I get a valid access token. When I use "pop_db.php" as my redirect instead of "complete.php" and therefore don't use any async calls, everything works fine.

Am I missing something? Why does it keep telling me the user isn't logged in?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but the `redirect_uri` should be an absolute url.

Answer (score 0):

Who are getting problem to login their own website thorough facebook / integrate facebook login to their website just follow the given link     "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/#step2".It is a very nice link which can solve your problem definitely.

Thanks.
banalata.

"